# best practice for a thumbnail alt tag that links to a larger image

Tags: html, alt

So I have a gallery full of thumbnails and each of them links to the full size image. how the alt tag should be implemented? I want search engines to find the large images using the text I provide in alt tag. Code is attached as below.

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="images/mustang1969.jpg">
<img src="images/mustang1969s.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your thumbnails not to show up in google image searches, you can create a common naming convention for your thumbnails that then matches a disallow pattern in you robots.txt.

```
 User-agent: Googlebot-Image
 Disallow: /*-thumb.png$
```

This way you can still put alt tags on your thumbnails to help with screen readers and things like that, but they will not show up in google image results.  Furthermore, if you set the user-agent to Googlebot-Image, then you can preserve the metadata of the thumbnail's alt tag for use as organic content for your page.

Comment: using this method, if I add an alt tag to the thumbnail img can the large photo it links to be indexed and be shown in Google search images?

Comment: yes, but the large image will need to use it's own alt tag; so, my suggestion is to do your SEO for the large image as what you want someone to search if doing an image search, and treat the alt text of the thumbnail as body content for the page itself.

Comment: How can the large image have its own `alt` attribute text? based on the code provided in the question is not possible. I can only add `alt` text to the thumbnail.

Comment: There are tons of ways to do this, but how I would do it is change <a href="images/mustang1969.jpg"> to <a href="imageBox.php?src=mustang1969&alt=some%20alt%20text%20here">.  Then make a very simple php page called imageBox.php that loads the GET values into the page containing an image so that is basicly nothing but <img src="images/<?=$_GET["src"]?>.jpg" alt="<?=urldecode ( $_GET["alt"])?>">

Comment: If you are not experienced with PHP, simply creating an HTML page to contain the images works too, but that's a lot of extra work if these galleries are going to be large.